# Read in binary data

Tags: r, tm, rodbc

Suppose I have data that's stored in a SQL Server database like so:

```
fileName     resumeData                             docType
Resume.pdf   0x255044462D312E350A25E2E3CFD30A3120   pdf
resume.doc   30206F626A0A3C3C200A2020202F54797      doc
```

(the resumeData field is truncated, obviously)

How do I read this data into R??

I can use the `RODBC` package to connect to the SQL server itself, and `select` from the table. When it reads the SQL data type `varbinary(max)`, R stores it as class `ODBC_bindary`.

How do I read this data? Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf) of `RODBC` package? It says that `varbinary(max)` is supported. I haven't tried though.

Comment: @alko989 Yes, `RODBC` can query for the data (and stores it as class `ODBC_binary`) but how can I read the raw text contents of this into R?